# How to use SQL connection dynamically Azure Logic Apps

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I need to insert data to dynamic databases from dynamic database connections. Is there any way to put connection related data to Azure Logic app code view?

Currently its generating following code to connect the database. But it is not dynamic, I need to configure connection related data at run time, not at design time.

```
"$connections": {
    "value": {
        "sql_1": {
            "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg_mazure_dev/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-3",
            "connectionName": "sql-3",
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/australiasoutheast/managedApis/sql"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dynamic connection feature is not available but on out backlog coming soon. Please vote on UserVoice to help us prioritize!

Comment: @DerekLi As of June 2019 this still doesn't seem available. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Standard connectors may not help you in this scenario. How about creating a custom connector and extend your logic app? 
please refer to this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app

You can also consider using Function App and incorporate into your logic app. Within this function, you can write your custom code to handle dynamic connections to DB.

Hope that helps.

Mihir

Answer (score 1):

Try using variables. At design time it will show an error. At run time though, it will work.

```
"path":"/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(variables('serverName')))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(variables('DbName')))}/query/sql"
```